# Solidity price calculation from USD to WEI

Tags: math, ethereum, solidity

im working on a project using [Oraclize](http://www.oraclize.it/) i get 1 ETH price in USD (1 ETH = 1e18 WEI) from coinmarketcap i.e. `474.846` using `parseInt` of Oraclize i can parse it to `uint256`. Due to lack of floating point data types i have an issue in calculating how many `wei` is any given USD price i.e. `0.001176470588235$` any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your own decimal offset so you can use integers in your contract. So, instead of working with 1 wei = x US dollars, you need to say (for example) 1 wei = x one-thousandths of a penny, where x is an integer. You have to decide how much precision you need.